# Wrong border color inside anchor in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, border

please look at the link:

http://rogatka.eu/content/23-poradnik-gardena

[image: Wrong border-bottom color in Chrome]

Inside those orange boxes, anchors have applied border-bottom:1px dashed #fff (and solid on hover). However, part of the border, as you can see, is not white - it gets #f3a889 instead. What may be causing this behaviour? It occurs only in Chrome.

HTML:

```
<div id="special1a">
   <h2><a title="Program do wyboru produktu" href="http://rogatka.eu/content/14-program-do-wyboru-produktu">Program do wyboru produktu &gt;&gt;&gt;</a></h2>
   <p>Czy potrzebują Państwo pomocy przy wyborze odpowiedniego produktu do pielęgnacji trawnika, drzew i krzewów?</p>
</div>
<div id="special1b">
   <h2><a title="Wybór właściwej pompy" href="http://www.gardena.com/pl/support/planners-and-guides/pump-guide/">Wybór właściwej pompy &gt;&gt;&gt;</a></h2>
   <p>Wypompowywanie, nawadnianie czy zaopatrywanie domu w wodę: wybierz pompę GARDENA spełniającą Twoje potrzeby.</p>
</div>
<div id="special1c">
   <h2><a title="Programy do projektowania" href="http://rogatka.eu/content/16-programy-do-projektowania">Programy do projektowania &gt;&gt;&gt;</a></h2>
   <p><a title="Projektowanie Micro-Drip" href="http://www.gardena.com/pl/support/planners-and-guides/micro-drip-planner/">Projektowanie Micro-Drip</a></p>
   <p><a title="Projektowanie Sprinklersystem" href="http://mygarden.gardena.com/pl/">Projektowanie Sprinklersystem</a></p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#special1a {
    background:#E75012 url(../img/bgSpecial1a.png) 796px center no-repeat;
    color:#fff;
    padding:20px 192px 20px 20px;
    margin:0 0 20px;
}
#special1b {
    background:#E75012 url(../img/bgSpecial1b.png) 796px center no-repeat;
    color:#fff;
    padding:20px 192px 20px 20px;
    margin:0 0 20px;
}
#special1c {
    background:#E75012 url(../img/bgSpecial1c.png) 796px center no-repeat;
    color:#fff;
    padding:20px 192px 20px 20px;
}
#special1a h2, #special1a h2 a, #special1a p, #special1a p a, #special1a p a:hover, #special1b h2, #special1b h2 a, #special1b p, #special1b p a, #special1b p a:hover, #special1c h2, #special1c h2 a, #special1c p, #special1c p a, #special1c p a:hover {
    color:#fff !important;
}
#special1a h2 a, #special1a h2 a:link, #special1a h2 a:visited, #special1a p a, #special1a p a:link, #special1a p a:visited, #special1b h2 a, #special1b h2 a:link, #special1b h2 a:visited, #special1b p a, #special1b p a:link, #special1b p a:visited, #special1c h2 a, #special1c h2 a:link, #special1c h2 a:visited, #special1c h2 a, #special1c h2 a:link, #special1c h2 a:visited {
    color:#fff !important;
    border-bottom:1px dashed #fff;
}
#special1a h2 a:hover, #special1a p a:hover, #special1b h2 a:hover, #special1b p a:hover, #special1c h2 a:hover, #special1c p a:hover {
    color:#fff !important;
    border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
}
#special1a p, #special1b p, #special1c p {
    margin:0 !important;
    font-family: 'MyriadPro-Light' !important;
    font-size:21px !important;
    line-height:140% !important;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-0.03deg);
}
#special1a h2, #special1b h2, #special1c h2 {
    font-family: 'MyriadPro-Bold' !important;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-0.03deg);
}
```

Comment: If you inspect the element, there's nothing to indicate that it is changing color.  Probably just some sort of odd color bleed.

Comment: I'm not seeing it here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/GEb7B/

Comment: @j08691 For me this issue also occurs in your link. What version of Chrome do you have? Mine is 26.0.1410.64 m

Comment: Version 26.0.1410.64 m

Answer (score 0):

You are rotating the title slightly (why?)

```
#special1a h2, #special1b h2, #special1c h2 {
    font-family: 'MyriadPro-Bold' !important;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-0.03deg);
}
```

Remove the rotation and you will be fine.

Comment: I'm rotating it because of the wrong antialiasing of fonts in Chrome. However, with or without rotate, issue still occurs.

Comment: You declared multiple times, apply `-webkit-transform: none !important` and you will see what I mean. If you still want to fix antialiasing this way then the only workaround I can think of is having the underline being a separate element.